# Parsing numbers from standard input stream using sscanf in C

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

Parsing numbers from standard input stream using sscanf in C

I have a text file which contains rows that start with a letter and then are followed by unsigned integers (some times a pair and other times just one).  At the begging of each row is a letter to categorize the row.  (see below) I’m able to get the content of the file and read it to screen. However, I am struggling with using sscanf to extract the letter and each integer from each row. So the results would be char, int and int all in separate variables - just using the ‘a’ row as an example.  I’ve been using the below code. The best I’ve gotten is that sscanf causes the strange behavior of giving all zeros. Again, I’m trying to get the char and each int into separate variables.

Sample of rows from text file

```
a -1109180 699692587
a 1213834231 -226769626
c 994957275 2082945813
e 1213834231


//The Code Used//////////////

char *line = NULL;
size_t size;
int results;

int val1;
int val2; 

while (getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1){

    if(strstr(line,"a") != NULL){

        sscanf(line,"Val1 and Val2: %d %d", val1,val2);
        printf("Value1 %d\n",val1);
        printf("Value2 %d\n",val2);

    }

//This prints each line in file 
printf("%s\n", line);

}
```

Kinda clueless on what’s missing here. Is sscanf the best method to achieve this in C or is there a simpler alternative?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"Val1 and Val2: %d %d"` doesn't match input. `sscanf(line,"Val1 and Val2: %d %d", val1,val2);` --> `sscanf(line, "a %d %d", &val1, &val2);`

Comment: Turn on warnings, that's usually `-Wall`. They'll catch a bunch of mistakes.

Comment: Check return value of `sscanf()` too.  Is it 2?

Comment: And don't forget to `free (line);` when it is no longer needed (remember, it is dynamically allocated by `getline`). Yes, it is freed when the program exits, but get  in the habit of tracking and freeing any memory you allocate.

Comment: Thanks. You guys rock! That did it. However, because some rows have two integers and others have one, each time I do sscanf(line,"%c%d",&category,&val1); on a row with one integer and then print("GET VAL1: %d\n",val1); it won't even compile. I get the following error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_print"    If this is not related to the original question, my apologies and I'll start a new question. You've been a big help.

Comment: @Ethan-Anthony `print` --> `printf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethan, some times you just need to slow down to help C fall into place. I your case you have data that evidently will contain a classification character in the beginning row of each line. That can be following by one or two number you need to read and handle accordingly. Your problem is defined by your dataset.

Thankfully, you can utilize *line-oriented* input functions `fgets` or `getline` and then a single call to `sscanf` for each like to handle all cases. After reading your line, you pass it to a `sscanf` call similar to the following:

```
rtn = sscanf (buf, "%c %d %d", &c, &v1, &v2);  /* always check return */
```

Preserving the return (i.e. the number of successful conversions that took place based upon your *format string*), you can began answering logical questions about the data you can expect. However before blindly comparing whether there are three, or two, or less conversions, you can answer simple questions just by looking at the first char in your buffer. If you require a lowercase letter to begin a valid line, then all you need to do is dereference your buffer to get the first char and then check if it is between `'a' - 'z'`. If not, it's not a valid line. Similarly, if you check the first char and find it `0` (the terminating char) or `'\n'`, then you know the line is empty and you need not bother with it any more. Those two test will filter out all the crud leaving you with at least lines that may match your criteria. For instance simply checking:

```
    if (rtn == 0) { /* no successful conversions took place */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no values parsed from line.\n");
        continue;
    }

    if (!*buf || *buf == '\n') {    /* check if buf was empty line */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: line is empty or contians only newline.\n");
        continue;
    }

    if (*buf < 'a' || 'z' < *buf) {  /* check first char not a-z */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no lowercase char beginning line.\n");
        continue;
    }
```

gives you confidence that at least the line you operated on had a reasonable chance of matching what you are looking for.

Now you can either do and `if ... else if .... else if ....` (which is perfectly fine), or since you know you are primarily concerned with checking values `1-3`, a `switch` statement makes sense for handling the remaining lines. For example, you could do something like the following to parse the value from those line that warrant a look:

```
    switch (rtn) {  /* switch on number of successful conversions */

        case 3:     /* three successful conversions */
            printf ("all values: '%c'  %d  %d\n", c, v1, v2);
            break;

        case 2:     /* two successful conversions */
            printf ("two values: '%c'  %d\n", c, v1);
            break;

        default:    /* one or less (need at least two */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: no character and value on line.\n");
    }
```

Putting all those pieces together, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 256

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin))    /* read each line into buf */
    {
        char c;
        int v1, v2, rtn;     /* vars for values and sscanf return */

        rtn = sscanf (buf, "%c %d %d", &c, &v1, &v2); 

        if (rtn == 0) { /* no successful conversions took place */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: no values parsed from line.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!*buf || *buf == '\n') {    /* check if buf was empty line */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line is empty or contians only newline.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (*buf < 'a' || 'z' < *buf) {  /* check first char not a-z */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: no lowercase char beginning line.\n");
            continue;
        }

        switch (rtn) {  /* switch on number of successful conversions */

            case 3:     /* three successful conversions */
                printf ("all values: '%c'  %d  %d\n", c, v1, v2);
                break;

            case 2:     /* two successful conversions */
                printf ("two values: '%c'  %d\n", c, v1);
                break;

            default:    /* one or less (need at least two */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: no character and value on line.\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input Files**

```
$ cat dat/input.txt
a -1109180 699692587
a 1213834231 -226769626
c 994957275 2082945813
e 1213834231
```

And a little messier file:

```
$ cat dat/rows.txt
a -1109180 699692587
a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
a 1213834231 -226769626

c 994957275 2082945813
227 isn't good
e 1213834231
```

Should provide a good test to see if the code does what you need it to do. Running your data through the code provides:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ /bin/sscanf_mixed <dat/input.txt
all values: 'a'  -1109180  699692587
all values: 'a'  1213834231  -226769626
all values: 'c'  994957275  2082945813
two values: 'e'  1213834231
```

The messier file output:

```
$ ./bin/sscanf_mixed <dat/rows.txt
all values: 'a'  -1109180  699692587
error: no character and value on line.
all values: 'a'  1213834231  -226769626
error: line is empty or contians only newline.
all values: 'c'  994957275  2082945813
error: no lowercase char beginning line.
two values: 'e'  1213834231
```

As you can see, both input files provided the same number of conversions, the second simply noting the error or problem that took place when non-conforming line are encountered.

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions. There are many ways to approach the logic of the problem, but which ever way you choose, you want to make sure you build all input routines flexible enough to handle those conditions (empty line, etc...) that you should reasonably expect to encounter in real world use.

Comment: David, you are an amazing instructor / guide. I understood and was able to achieve everything, per your explanation. I sincerely thank you.  Again, I have never seen anyone explain C with such clarity. THX! Also, note that I'm taking into account ALL of your suggestions / pointers and will amend them to my near term study objectives.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Sometimes it just takes a little help to get going with C. It really is one of the (if not the) most flexible and efficient language you can learn. But there is a lot to it. The best advise I ever got was to simply "slow down", "check the man page" for each function used, and "always make use of the return" to validate the results of each function call you use. (and to always compile with *warnings enabled*, e.g. with `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string, and never accept code until it compiles without warnings)